# How to change the activation events of an installed extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code version `Version: 1.65.0` on mac os. I have vscodevim extension installed. By default, activation events mentioned in the `~/.vscode/extensions/vscodevim.vim-1.22.2/package.json` file of vscodevim are:

```
    "activationEvents": [
        "*",
        "onCommand:type"
    ],
```

I want vscodevim extension to activate only for certain languages, let's say for Python. I tried changing the activation events setting as below in the package.json and restarted the VS Code but it didn't work.

```
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:python"
    ],
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the extension `package.json` will be lost on extension update.

You can disable the extension globally and enable it for your python workspaces.

Once you have activated an extension in a workspace it stays active. So if you open a Python file and then edit an HTML file you get also the vim behavior.

You can define a set of key bindings that select the input mode you want for the current file:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
  "command": "toggleVim",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python' && vim.mode == 'Disabled'"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
  "command": "toggleVim",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId != 'python' && vim.mode != 'Disabled'"
}
```